# Compute primitive $ \int{ \sin(x) \sqrt{ 1-x^2 } } dx$

Tags: integration

Solving a double integral in spherical coordinates of the projected cosine of a spherical cap, the following integral is an "interesting" sub-problem.

It seems more difficult than it looks. Any ideas?

$$ \int{ \sin(x) \sqrt{ 1-x^2 } } dx$$

assuming x is between 0 and 1.

Partial integration and substitution were not helpful because the sine as well as the root do not have easy derivatives or antiderivatives.

Neither Mathematica nor Maple nor Rubi are able to solve it.

I know about StruveH for the definite integral but that's not the question.

Comment: This function has no antiderivative.

Comment: Yes it has one. You can plot it numerically.

Comment: I meant not by elementary functions.

Comment: The substitution $x= \cos(u)$  doesn't work here because because$\frac{du}{dx} = -\sin(u)$ This does not cancel out the $\sin(x)$ as it is with a different variable.

$$\int \sin(x) \sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \int \sin(\cos(u))*\sqrt{1-\cos^2(u)}*\frac{1}{-\sin(u)}du$$

Comment: I don't think there's any easy antiderivative, WolframAlpha exceeds computation time:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%7Bsin(x)*sqrt(1-x%5E2)%7D

Comment: Mathematica outputs $\frac{\pi}{2} H_1(1)$ where $H_n$ is the [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Comment: I know. And Maple and Rubi are not able to find an answer. I told you it "looks" easy.

Comment: @anderstood: just for a definitive integral between 0 and 1. But not between 0.1 and 0.2, for example.

Comment: @anderstood: I included Mathematica etc and made it clear that it is an indefinite integral. Assuming x between 0 and 1 might help because there are no singularities.

Comment: @G.S. From which textbook is this problem?

Comment: No textbook. It's a real problem. :)